# setInterval Function - Inquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need help with getting a "setInterval(function(){}" function to work with my code.

The function should display a  popup message when the number of yellow cells equals the number of red cells. I've include my code below and a picture of the concept.  Help Please! :-)

Here is the JavaScript that I want to do the popup message.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
var reds = document.getElementByClassName('red_block')
var yellows = document.getElementByClassName('yellow_block')
if(reds.length == yellows.length){
alert("what ever")
}
}, 1);
```

Here is the code that I have right now.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var color = "White";
      $("#btnWhite").click(function() {
        color = "#FFFFFF"
      });
      $("#btnYellow").click(function() {
        color = "#FFFF00"
      });
      $("#btnRed").click(function() {
        color = "#FF0000"
      });


      $("table tr td").click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
      });


    });
```

```css
        body {
          padding: 5px;
        }
        
        label {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        input[type=button] {
          padding: 10px 16px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        p {
          margin: 1em 0 0;
        }
        
        td.pz {
          border: thin solid #000000;
          width: 59px;
          height: 57px;
          background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        
        .red_block {
          border: thin solid #000000;
          width: 59px;
          height: 57px;
          background-color: #FF0000;
        }
        
        .yellow_block {
          border: thin solid #000000;
          width: 59px;
          height: 57px;
          background-color: #FFFF00;
        }
        
        td.padding {
          width: 59px;
          height: 57px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="btnWhite" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px dotted #999" value="">
  <input id="btnYellow" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FFFF00; border: 1px dotted #999" value="">
  <input id="btnRed" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FF0000; border: 1px dotted #999" value="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
      <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

[image: example colored table]

Comment: You have to end each line with a ;

Comment: Why do you need `setInterval`? You could check the length of each color of box after changing it, no?

Comment: In addition to lack of ending a line with a terminator (;), where exactly are you calling your setInterval function in your code?

Comment: Is `getElementByClassName` a typo here?  Because it doesn't exist, it should be `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: As the cells change when someone clicks on them, @Mr.Meeseeks is spot on, there's no reason to poll the result, just check whenever someone clicks, and the color changes

Comment: You are not adding or removing classes so what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Jonasw JavaScript has [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion), so you don't _need_ to insert them on every line.  I'm not getting into whether it's a good idea or not here though...

Comment: @James Thorpe : Oh i didnt know this. I think its more readable, and you can find them in nearly every code so i prefer using them.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for your answers. Both solutions are awesome!!!

Comment: I have one more request. Is it possible to add a clause that the whole table has to be complete + #reds == #yellows then the alert is dislplayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the CSS classes you've defined, rather than setting a background color directly. That way, you can count the blocks that have each class. For efficiency, I also suggest counting after each click, rather than using a timer to count periodically.

I've also added a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) to each button to help reduce code redundancy. When any button is clicked, the "brush" is set to the color class associated with that button. That class will subsequently be applied to any clicked block.

```js
jQuery(function() {

  var brush = "white_block";

  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });

  jQuery('td').on('click',function() {

    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);

    var reds = jQuery('.red_block').length,
        yellows = jQuery('.yellow_block').length;

    if (reds == yellows) {
      console.log('MATCH');
    } else {
      console.log('MISMATCH');
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}
.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin:1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
<input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
<input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply count how many cells have background-color red/yellow using [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$(function () {
  var color = "#FFFFFF";
  $("#btnWhite").click(function() {
    color = "#FFFFFF"
  });
  $("#btnYellow").click(function() {
    color = "#FFFF00"
  });
  $("#btnRed").click(function() {
    color = "#FF0000"
  });


  $("table tr td").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", color);

    var reds = $("table tr td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    })
    var yellows  = $("table tr td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    })


    if (reds.length == yellows.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {alert("what ever")}, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=button] {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}

td.pz {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.red_block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.yellow_block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

td.padding {
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<input id="btnWhite" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px dotted #999" value="">
<input id="btnYellow" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FFFF00; border: 1px dotted #999" value="">
<input id="btnRed" type='button' style="font-face: 'Arial'; width: 50px; font-size: larger; color: Black; background-color: #FF0000; border: 1px dotted #999" value="">
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="yellow_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
        <td class="red_block"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks.